# How to replace part of column String SQLite3 with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, replace

I have a database with some problematic characters in a specific column from improper importing, and I want to replace them with the proper ones.

For example, I want to replace `&quot;` with `"` where ever it is found in a string in the column `English` of the Table Data.

I'm using the following code to no avail:

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('Solutions.db')
c = conn.cursor()
sql = """SELECT English, replace(English,'&quot;','"') FROM Data"""
c.execute(sql)
records = c.fetchall()
print("Total rows are:  ", len(records))
print("Printing each row")
for row in records:
    print(row[0])
    print("\n")
conn.commit()
```

I noticed in the debugger that the `sql =` line translates like this:

```
sql = SELECT English, replace(English,\ `'&quot;` \',\'"\') FROM Data
```

It is putting a `\` before every `'` and I don't know if this is normal behavior. 
Either way, I'm not getting the characters replaced, but if I run the same exact command directly into the sqlite3 it makes the changes just fine.

I'm using Python 3.7.5

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you expecting it to update the data in the database or only while retrieving? If you want to update in the database, you need to run `UPDATE` sql statement instead of `SELECT`.

Comment: Im expecting to update the data in Database. So i tried what you said and with UPDATE im getting an error:

c.execute(sql)

sqlite3.OperationalError: near ",": syntax error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is you are printing the first column which is `English` whereas the replacement is actually happening in the second column of your resultset.

if you update the following line to look for index 1 instead of 0, you'll get the correct results.

```
...
for row in records:
    print(row[1])  # print the second column defined by your replace function.
    print("\n")
...
```

However, it is still not going to update the actual data in the database because `SELECT` only queries the data and `REPLACE` is performed on the queried copy of the data. To update the data in your database, you need to perform the `UPDATE` operation on the database column.

```
UPDATE
    Data
SET
    English = REPLACE(English,'&quot;','"');
```

Comment: Though now im messing with another problem, i cant replace the following

English = REPLACE(English,'&#39;',"'");    

i cant find a way how to put ' in there without having error code

Comment: SOLUTION: I found that you can ' as two single quotes in a row like this "''"

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE test(English);
INSERT INTO test(English) VALUES
  ("a&quot;b&quot;c"),
  ("d&quot;e&quot;f");
.headers on
SELECT * from test;

.print Updating
UPDATE test SET English = replace(replace(English, "&quot;", """"), "&39;", "'");
SELECT * from test;
```

```
$ sqlite3 < english.sql
English
a&quot;b&quot;c&39;x&39;
d&quot;e&quot;f
Updating
English
a"b"c'x'
d"e"f
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer Peak as well.

Though now im struggling to replace &#39 with ' as if i put ' between " " im getting unexpected token error.